# D3: Creating responsive range bar chart

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to create a range bar chart in D3 (see [a similar example](https://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/range-bar-chart/)).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34086121/445817), and I was able to customize it into exactly what I needed, except that it uses an ancient version of D3, the data is in a silly format of separate arrays, and it's not responsive (why is so much D3 stuff out there not responsive?).

I abandoned that attempt, and started over from scratch. I now have it mostly working using the latest D3 and some ideas from the SO question above, but the data is not quite displaying correctly. When I resize, the bars grow and shrink unpredictably, eventually getting negative width values as I make it wider.

I'd appreciate help understanding what I'm doing wrong with the bar sizes. Please note, to observe the incorrect behavior, you'll have to expand the snippet and resize the window.

```js
let data = [
  { field: "Field Name 1", salary: [42, 65], bonusRange: [null, null] },
  { field: "Field Name 2", salary: [28, 58], bonusRange: [null, null] },
  { field: "Field Name 3", salary: [33, 57], bonusRange: [null, null] },
  { field: "Field Name 4", salary: [33, 50], bonusRange: [null, null] },
  { field: "Field Name 5", salary: [32, 44], bonusRange: [38, 52] },
  { field: "Field Name 6", salary: [27, 40], bonusRange: [null, null] }
];

const chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
const svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");

function redraw() {
  svg.selectAll("g").remove();

  const margin = 20;
  const width = chartDiv.clientWidth - margin * 2;
  const height = chartDiv.clientHeight - margin * 2;

  svg
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([120, width - 10])
    .domain([20, 70]);

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([0, height - margin])
    .domain([-0.5, (data.length - 1) * 1.1]);

  const yAxis = d3
    .axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(data.length)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      return data[i].field;
    });

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin})`);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(120, 0)");

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "bars")
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .style("fill", "#f61166")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.salary[0]);
    })
    .attr("height", 25)
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.salary[1] - d.salary[0]);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return yScale(i) - margin * 0.5;
    });
}

redraw();
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

#chart {
  outline: 1px solid fuchsia;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 59.75%;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

#chart svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needed a lot of refactoring, you should in general follow the d3 [**update pattern**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) whenever you want to change data (or size of window in this case, *ps. I'm not 100% certain that this is a good idea since I never make my charts "responsive" like this, but it seems to work just fine*)

In other words, don't use `svg.selectAll("g").remove();` when you want to update, you can obviously but that's not really idiomatic to d3.

I removed all the appending out of the redraw function and put them in a wrapper function so we can reference them either by class name or varaible.

I also made your yScale variable into a scaleband so that it's easier to resize the chart based on data.

```
const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.field))
    .padding(0.1)
    .paddingOuter(0.1)
    .paddingInner(0.1);
```

I've added a snippet below, hopefully it should be clear how something like this can be done.

```js
let data = [
 { field: "Field Name 1", salary: [42, 65], bonusRange: [null, null] },
 { field: "Field Name 2", salary: [28, 58], bonusRange: [null, null] },
 { field: "Field Name 3", salary: [33, 57], bonusRange: [null, null] },
 { field: "Field Name 4", salary: [33, 50], bonusRange: [null, null] },
 { field: "Field Name 5", salary: [32, 44], bonusRange: [38, 52] },
 { field: "Field Name 6", salary: [27, 40], bonusRange: [null, null] }
];

chart(data);

function chart(data) {

 var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
  margin = {top: 55, bottom: 0, left: 85, right: 0},
  width  = parseInt(svg.style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = parseInt(svg.style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
 const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([20, 70]);

 const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.field))
  .padding(0.1)
  .paddingOuter(0.1)
  .paddingInner(0.1);

 const xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")

 const yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")

 redraw(width, height);

 function redraw(width, height) {

  yScale.range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
 
  svg.selectAll(".y-axis")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(data.length)
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
     return data[i].field;
       }));
 
  xScale.range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

  svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(0)
   .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
 
  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(data)

  bar.exit().remove();

  bar.enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .style("fill", "#f61166")
   .merge(bar)
  .transition().duration(0)
   .attr("width", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.salary[1] - d.salary[0]) - xScale(0);
   })
   .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
   .attr("y", d => yScale(d.field))
   .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.salary[0]);
   });
 }

 d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
  width = parseInt(svg.style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = parseInt(svg.style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  redraw(width, height);
 });
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
 font: 18px arial;
}
#chart {
 outline: 1px solid fuchsia;
 position: absolute;
 width: 95%;
 height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

Comment: This is a really great answer. I really wasn't intending to get this deep into D3, since I just have to get a few of charts into a site I'm working on, and I've been c3.js, which uses D3 and works perfectly for most of them. I just pass it some pretty simple configuration and it does the rest. The only problem is that it doesn't support this type of chart.

Comment: While I have your attention… the API changes from a year or so ago broke basically everything. How did the D3 community take this? It makes it really hard to Google for help because a lot of stuff older than a year ago is broken with the latest D3… which means it's easy to miss a lot of stuff that's still relevant. Again, thanks for your help. These are some really great pointers that can help me with the next pieces of this that I still need to build.

Comment: @freshyill glad it helped! If the later version of d3 "breaks" your code then just stick with the older version until you have time to properly upgrade it to the newer one. You can see what has changed in the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) . As for the API, it is a bit broken indeed (in terms of older links no longer working etc) but that's hopefully being worked on.